Object doesn't move after clear parent
Downloaded object from BlenderKit and after I clear parent (as there are a lot of extra stuff I don't need) it doesn't move at all in Object mode. Surprisingly it DOES move in edit mode. Is there a way to make it move in Object as well?
Edit. Added pictures: trying to move in Object mode - nothing. Moving in Edit - moves.
Also to wasn't able to move anything while object was parented, this is after Clear parent.



Hello, please add more context, some picture of your outliner / 3D viewport

Did you look at the properties of the object to see if the location is locked? Did you check your "options" to see if you have something like "origins only" and similars?

omg it WAS locked, thank you! I've never encountered a locked object like this before so it didn't occur to me as a possibility!
